# Customize the Decryption Password Screen on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, customizer

So my Ubuntu is encrypted and whenever it ask me to decrypt the drive it says something like "Please enter the password for sda3_crypt" or something like that. Is there a way to customize what the message says? If so, how?